# How to use placeholder with Meteor AutoForm select2?

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-select2, meteor-autoform

I am using the AutoForm package including the select2 extension for Meteor.

> aldeed:autoform
>
> aldeed:autoform-select2

The documentation on autoform-select2 tells me I can set use select2Options like this:

```
{{> afQuickField name='finalReviewerComments'select2Options=select2Options}}
```

My schema:

```
finalReviewerComments: {
    type: String,
    max: 20,
    autoform: {
        options: [
            {label: "Good", value: 0},
            {label: "9: Grammar/spelling/formatting/readability", value: 9},
            {label: "8: Not a finding", value: 8},
            {label: "7: Information missing", value: 7},
            {label: "6: Repeated/combined finding", value: 6},
            {label: "5: FAQ requirements", value: 5},
            {label: "4: Multiple findings in one", value: 4},
            {label: "3: Context missing", value: 3},
            {label: "2: Country/page number error", value: 2},
            {label: "1: Misinterpretation", value: 1}
        ],
        type: "select2"
    },
    optional: true
}
```

I tried both adding this to my schema inside autoform:

```
afFieldInput: {
    select2Options: {
        placeholder: "Imaginary text here"
    }
}
```

And using a helper function select2Options as pointed out in the docs:

```
Template.finalReview.helpers({
    select2Options: function () {
        return {placeholder: "Final Review Comments"};
    }
});
```

Neither of the two options work. How can I get it to work? I want an empty select2 input box when the form is rendered.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify: `{allowclear: true}` didn't work either.

Comment: Could you please try to use `afFieldInput` instead of an `afQuickField` element?

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder is blank by default. To add an actual value, this works, as the documentation states:

Helper file:

```
Template.testTemplate.helpers({
    select2Options: function () {
        return {placeholder: "Find a dataset"};
    }
})
```

Template file:

```
<template name="testTemplate">
    {{#autoForm id='addDatasetForm' schema=datasetsSchema type='normal' class="form-horizontal" validation='keyup'}}
        {{> afQuickField class='select2 select-css' name=dataset_name options=getDatasets size=10 select2Options=select2Options}}
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

It returns:
[image: Select2 field with placeholder]

Although now that I have provided this answer, the placeholder appears to not show up the first time the template is rendered. This particular field is part of an array field, and it only shows up once I've removed and then re-added an element to the array field.